# How to start Designer Workflow on Retention Label

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, records-center

Hi I want to start my WF and send an email , when an user applied Retention Label on Item , is it possible, because when i tried item  does not get modified when i Retention applied Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to send an email by workflow when an user applies retention label on items.

Comment: Thank you even I think so